Unable to Import Opencv while converting .py to .exe executable file even after applying multiple solutions. Missing configuration file: ['config.py']
I have been trying to convert one of my OpenCV projects into an executable file using PyInstaller. The file is working in my command prompt, but whenever I try to run it through the .exe, I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "cv2\__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
  File "cv2\__init__.py", line 111, in bootstrap
  File "cv2\__init__.py", line 109, in load_first_config
ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']. Check OpenCV installation.

I have already tried the following solutions:

Providing the cv2 path before executing the PyInstaller command.
Downgrading the Python version to the minimum, as I'm using Ultralytics as one of the libraries.
Uninstalling and reinstalling OpenCV.
Ensuring all versions are compatible.
Downloading the latest version of PyInstaller from GitHub.
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/tarball/develop

I'm not sure what else I should do from here. Please help me troubleshoot this issue.

How old is your Python and OpenCV?  This bug was reported and fixed in 2021.

My python version is 3.11.9 and of OpenCV is 4.10.0

Well, somehow you need to tell Pyinstaller that it has to include config.py.  The OpenCV setup is supposed to do that.

Thank you, I was able to make it work but did a lot of changes in the versions given below:
python==3.7.0
opencv-python==4.5.3.56
pyinstaller==5.2
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib 2022.8
torch==1.13.0
torchvision==0.14.0
